# Can we use javascript & C# xaml both in windows Phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to know can we use both javascript & xaml C# both in windows phone

e.g. say when i click on xaml button a javascript function called .

If yes then please tell me how it would done ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to get your job done!

Here is another link: 
     [Windows Phone App](http://ax2012aifintegration.blogspot.com/2013/11/mvvm-windows-phone-8-app-using.html)

Yes, Visual Studio 2012 provides a template to build HTML5 apps. This template is available with WP8 SDK. Alternatively you can use Phonegap, Titanium, Sencha.

https://github.com/matthiasxc/WP8-HTML-Tutorials